# Download a file from remote server in UNIX

Tags: unix, ftp, command-line-interface, wget, sftp

I have a file on a remote server that I can connect to via ssh. I would like to copy the file from the remote server at the path: '/home/example.txt' to my computer's desktop.

Should I be using **wget**, **sftp**, **ftp**, or simply **rm**?

Bonus points if you know a good resource for UNIX documentation, since google's results were not great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`scp(1)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=scp&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html):

```
~$ scp user@host:/home/example.txt .
```

Comment: what does the period at the end do?

Comment: Means "current directory".

Comment: @tumultous_rooster period is for current directory

Answer (score 2):

None of them, you should use [scp](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_scp.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`scp` or `rcp` if you don't want/need to be secured.  Or alternatively `rsync` will be nicer for anything more complicated with remote file transferring on a regular basis.

For the documentation, look at the `man` pages, ex: `man scp`.  Or online at

- http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/rcp
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Answer (score 0):

Try Filezilla Utility
More info on http://filezilla-project.org/